# Google Play won't accept Apache Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I originally tried using [AIDE for PhoneGap](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.phonegap&hl=en) and after I submitted my app to Google Play I got the following message...

***APP REJECTED***
Your app submission has been rejected because it contains security vulnerabilities, which is a violation of our [dangerous products](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html#dangerous) policy. If the uploaded APK was an app update, the previous version is still available on Google Play. More details about this rejection have been emailed to the account owner.

I then went ahead and used [Apache Cordova's](https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted) Hello World example after a fresh npm install and received the following message (At this point I did not check the full error to see what version of Cordova was reqjected)...

***Security alert***
This app is built on a version of Apache Cordova that contains security vulnerabilities. You have until Aug 31, 2015 to resolve this. Please see the alerts page for more information.
Affects APK version 6.

My last attempt was using Adobe's [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) as a work around (after reading the full alert on Google Play... "Please migrate your app to Apache Cordova v.3.5.1 or higher as soon as possible.") and Google Play still gave the message above. BTW My app runs fine on Android I just haven't got it accepted into Google Play.

I've been searching for a solution since last night and I haven't came across anything, and I would much rather prefer to use Adobe's [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) than going into native Java.

Can anyone help? I don't know why these are not working for me.

After running `npm info cordova` It says the version is **6.0.0** but the cordova.js file says it's version **5.1.0**. PhoneGap Desktop doesn't give me a cordova file, but `npm info phonegap` version says it's **5.4.1**.

I updated the old cordova.js file to the most recent one being v5.1.0, but haven't figured out how to replace `cordova-2.9.0.jar`. to version v5.4.1

**NOTE**: Even with cordova.js v5.1.0 it's still not being accepted on Google Play.

Here's my config.xml (for PhoneGap Build)...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
  xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
  id          = "com.michael.hellp"
  version     = "1.0.0">
  <name>
    Hello world
  </name>
  <description>
    Hello world description
  </description>
  <author href="http://build.phonegap.com/" email="name@website.com">
    Bruce Lee
  </author>

  <content src="index.html" />

  <icon src="icon.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="android" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
  <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
  <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
  <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
  <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />

  <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question...is there some reason you can't use a recent version of Cordova?

Comment: After running `npm info cordova` It says the version is **6.0.0** but the cordova.js file says it's version **5.1.0**. PhoneGap desktop doesn't give me a cordova file, but `npm info phonegap` version says it's **5.4.1**.   

I updated the old cordova.js file to the most recent one being v5.1.0, but haven't figured out how to replace `cordova-2.9.0.jar`. to version v5.4.1

Comment: By the way I'm developing this on my Android Tablet and my Chromebook.

Comment: Sounds like your machine is a mess. Time to clean house and reinstall stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do with PhoneGap Build is add this line of code in my `config.xml` file.

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
```

So here's what my config looks like now.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
  xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
  id          = "com.michael.hellp"
  version     = "1.0.0">
  <name>
    Hello world
  </name>
  <description>
    Hello world description
  </description>
  <author href="http://build.phonegap.com/" email="name@website.com">
    Bruce Lee
  </author>

  <content src="index.html" />

  <icon src="icon.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="android" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
  <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
  <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
  <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
  <icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
  <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />

  <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />` setting as proposed by [Michael Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35230463/890242) did not help.

The following resolved the issue:

```
$ cordova platform remove android
$ cordova platform add android@5.4.0
```

To check what version you are actually submitting, check `platforms/android/platform_www/cordova.js` for the following string:

```
var PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL = '5.4.0';
```

Note changing this string manually will get you in trouble elsewhere, so don't.

Comment: What I see is the reason why `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />` did not work is because it's for PhoneGap Build and you're using PhoneGap CLI.

Comment: good point thanks. I added my answer here because that was the first question that popped up when I searched for _google play won't accept cordova app_ and I figured others might find it too....