# Why can't I change my android app version with phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, android-security

I always get rejected to put my app on the google playstore. I think I am being rejected because I can't change the version number of the app. I have tried literally annything and I always get this email :

[image]

When I type in **npm info cordova version** in the cmd I get back "6.3.1".

When I type in **phonegap -v** in the cmd I get back "6.3.1".

I changed my config.xml attributes to

```
<widget id="example" version="1.1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="6.3.0" />
```

I changed my AndroidManifest.xml attributes to

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10001" android:versionName="1.0.1" package="be.matroesjkas" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

I added this to my build.gradle file

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
```

I have removed the android platform and readded it with phonegap.

The version number on the phonegap build site always stays at 1.0.0 when I rebuild it.

Comment: Have you tried grepping through the apk to look for old version strings? You might have files from an old version of cordova sticking around somewhere. Other than that, if you upload the apk somewhere, I could take a look and try to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play won't accept Apache Cordova](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213715/google-play-wont-accept-apache-cordova)